# Get A Window's Bounds By Its Handle

Tags: c#, winapi, graphics

I am trying to get the height and the width of the current active window.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, Rectangle rect);

Rectangle bonds = new Rectangle();
GetWindowRect(handle, bonds);
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(bonds.Width, bonds.Height);
```

This code doesn't work because I need to use `RECT` and I don't know how.

Answer (score 35):

Things like this are easily answered by google (C# GetWindowRect); you should also know about pinvoke.net -- great resource for calling native APIs from C#.

http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/getwindowrect.html

I guess for completeness I should copy the answer here:

```
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct RECT
        {
            public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
            public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
            public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
            public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
        }

        Rectangle myRect = new Rectangle();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            RECT rct;

            if(!GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, this.Handle), out rct ))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                return;
            }
            MessageBox.Show( rct.ToString() );

            myRect.X = rct.Left;
            myRect.Y = rct.Top;
            myRect.Width = rct.Right - rct.Left;
            myRect.Height = rct.Bottom - rct.Top;
        }
```

Comment: Creating a new RECT struct is overkill, the System.Drawing.Rectangle layout is the same.

Comment: Yep, confirmed to be totally overkill: http://gyazo.com/09879c74a75029e7460347644d102dd0.png

Comment: @pikzen: It is not the same.  Rectangle has Width and Height, RECT has right and bottom.

Comment: @pikzen it's like saying using types is an overkill, it's all just bytes.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Wording is different, values are the same. The window in the screenshot I've posted isn't 1740px wide. Width corresponds to Right and Height corresponds to Bottom.

Comment: @pikzen - no, use Reflector to look at the private fields of Rectangle.  It really stores width and height, not right and bottom.  Different wording *and* different values.

Comment: It's also useful when you are working in a strict Console Application and don't have access to Forms namespaces.  I used this to center a Console window on the screen.

Comment: I think the width and height calculations should not have the +1.

Comment: Rectangle.FromLTRB(left, top, right, bottom) static function is a great help.

Comment: A gotcha that I didn't notice from the pinvoke example is that you need to use a struct, not a class.

Comment: Seconding what Kenneth said - the +1 in the width and height calculations is incorrect.

Comment: what is wrong with +1?  If you have a rectangle with coordinates of top left and bottom right corners of (0,0) and (2,2) what is the width of this rectangle?  It has a border at coordinate 0, another border at coordinate 2 and the inside empty space as coordinate 1.  So total width is 3.

Comment: Really old I know - but nobody answered this:
>>what is wrong with +1?

what is the width of a window when boderSize = 0 and the coordinates of the left = 0 and the coordinates of right = 0?

the answer with the +1 = 1 instead of 0

Comment: @SilverKnight so what is wrong with the width of 1 in that case?  It's a dot.

Comment: Oh wait they finally fixed the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect and it says that In conformance with conventions for the RECT structure, the bottom-right coordinates of the returned rectangle are exclusive. In other words, the pixel at (right, bottom) lies immediately outside the rectangle.  So yes, then there should be no +1

Comment: I confirm that it is wrong to use `System.Drawing.Rectangle`.  The `GetWindowRect()` function stores X1,Y1,X2,Y2 into the structure passed to it, but the fields of `System.Drawing.Rectangle` are actually X,Y,W,H, so when you query either the width and height of the rectangle or the location of its bottom-right corner, you get wrong results.  The whole discussion started by pikzen, complete with an alleged proof and all, is just a waste of time.

Answer (score -1):

Of course that code will not work. It has to be this way: `GetWindowRect(handle, ref rect);`. So, edit your `GetWindowRect` declaration. And `Rectangle` is just a wrapper of the native `RECT`. `Rectangle` and `RECT` has left, top, right and bottom fields that the Rectangle class changed to read-properties (`Left`, `Top`, `Right`, `Bottom`). `Width` is not equivalent to right and `Height` is not equivalent to bottom. `Width` is right-left and `Height` is bottom-top. Of course, `RECT` don't have these sort of properties. It's just a bare struct.

Creating `RECT` is an overkill. `Rectangle` is enough in .NET for native/unmanaged API that need it. You just have to pass it in the appropriate way.

Comment: I want to comment to the OP's post directly but since I can't, I'll just do it here. CharSet and ExactSpelling are not necessary. There's only one declaration of GetForegroundWindow in user32.dll. There's no ANSI and unicode versions.