# Classes missing from System.Windows.Forms in VS Code C# Console Application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code

I made a console application with the VS Code C# extension. I need a couple of classes from `System.Windows.Forms`, like `Screen` and `Cursor`. While I can access `System.Windows.Forms` itself, the classes in question aren't there. Are there some other references I need to add?

This is what my csproj file looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Forms and console apps are separate things, you can't 'borrow' forms classes for a console app.  What cursor are you trying to set in a console app?

Comment: I'm trying to get the current screen resolution and control the mouse cursor.

Comment: So, to get the screen width https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.virtualscreenwidth?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_SystemParameters_VirtualScreenWidth and for moving the mouse, I think you will have to use PInvoke https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setcursorpos

Comment: screen resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930612/get-screen-resolution-in-console-app

Comment: and for cursor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.setcursorposition?view=net-5.0