# Why would GetWindowRect return an enormous value for one coordinate?

Tags: c#, .net

For the maximized active window of a Windows 10 desktop application on a single display with resolution 1536x960, I am retrieving its coordinates through:

```
IntPtr hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();

Rectangle bounds = GetWindowRect(hwnd);

Console.WriteLine("Left: " + bounds.Left);
Console.WriteLine("Right: " + bounds.Right);
Console.WriteLine("Top: " + bounds.Top);
Console.WriteLine("Bottom: " + bounds.Bottom);
```

This outputs:

```
Left: 0  
Right: -2080342032  
Top: 0  
Bottom: 695
```

What are possible reasons the Right coordinate could be so messed up?

Comment: multiple desktops?

Comment: can you share your implementation of `GetWindowRect`?

Comment: Single screen. The laptop initially had a screen connected, but then the output was equally strange for the Right coordinate:

Left: 0  
Right: 2122350576  
Top: 0  
Bottom: 645

Comment: What is `GetWindowRect` here? The Windows API returns a `bool` and has a `ref` parameter for the bounds. Show us the rest of your code.

Comment: I get `GetWindowRect` from `[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern Rectangle GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd);`

Comment: yea that's going to cause problems with your stack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415222/get-a-windows-bounds-by-its-handle/6415255#6415255

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling [`GetWindowRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowrect) incorrectly. Try this, note it returns a `bool` and the bounds are given in an `out` parameter:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out Rectangle rectangle);
```

And call it like this:

```
if (!GetWindowRect(hwnd, out var bounds))
{
    throw new Win32Exception();
}

Console.WriteLine("Left: " + bounds.Left);
Console.WriteLine("Right: " + bounds.Right);
Console.WriteLine("Top: " + bounds.Top);
Console.WriteLine("Bottom: " + bounds.Bottom);
```

Comment: This returns the expected:

Left: -7  
Right: 1535  
Top: -7  
Bottom: 919